# The remote server returned an error 407 proxy authentication required

Tags: web-services, authentication, proxy, http-status-code-407

I'm getting this error when I call a web service in C#: "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required". I reference some topic but issue not fixed.

I was added in my .cs code before call ws function:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://doamin:9001", true);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

And in config I added in `<configuration>` tag:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
<proxy usesystemdefault="False"
proxyaddress="http://doamin:9001"
bypassonlocal="True"
autoDetect="False" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

After added some code I got another error: "The remote server returned an error 403 forbidden".
Please help me or give me an advice for this issue.
Thanks.